# How to add JS object with nested properties to URL?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, symfony, url

I have object similar to this structure:

```
filters = {
    filters: {
        categoryFilters: {
            mainCategory: value1,
            subCategory: value2
        }
    }
}
```

And I am dynamically updating an URL by adding active filters/sortings using:

```
url.searchParams.set('mainCategory', "val1")
window.history.replaceState(null, null, url)
```

I need to pass object with structure explained above, so I can use it as an associative array in PHP, e.g:

```
$filters = [
    "categoryFilters" => [
        "mainCategory" => val1,
        "childCategory" => val2,
        ...
    ]
]
```

I have no problem adding parameters to URL without nested properties, but I struggle with this one. The goal is to get data from URL, so the receiver of an URL (for example by copy-paste) would get the same result as sender.

Also, I am using Symfony.

Comment: You could encode it as JSON and then url-encode it within a query parameter, but it could get messy, or with a lot of data you could end up even exceeding the URL character limit. Consider flattening the structure a bit, or posting it as JSON within the request body instead of the URL

Comment: The common approach for this is to have a serializer that will replace all the names with `a, b, c, d, aa, ab, ac, ad, ... e.t.c.` and also convert values into shorter forms if possible. For example, instead of `value1` (if it is a fixed enum value, for example)  serializer can produce `v1`. Deserializer does the opposite to restore the original structure.

Comment: You mean like `?filters[categoryFilters][mainCategory]=value1&filters[categoryFilters][mainCategory2]=value2`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, something like that.

Comment: I updated my answer for more info.

Comment: Just add the key paths to your url params so they match. Like: `params.append('[filters][categoryFilters][mainCategory]', 'value1')` (using `URLSearchParams`)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank you, it works as intended. Since your suggestion allowed me to solve my problem, can you post it as an answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier than it seems, although it would be nice if you could pass an object to `URLSearchParams` and it would parse for you.

However, all you need to do is resolve each unique path using square brackets (no quotes) and add as a param key with associated value:

```
url.searchParams.set('[filters][categoryFilters][mainCategory]', 'value1')
```

A function could be written that would do that from an object, however this is what it would be doing (linearizing the unique key paths to an array), which would then be appended (like in `URLSearchParams`) or set (as in your example).